# How do I satisfy the AWS CDK Lambda's CfnFunction "code" parameter in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, yaml

I'm attempting to translate a YAML CloudFormation template into AWS's CDK using Python. I am currently stuck on instantiating a lambda CfnFunction.  It appears that I am not satisfying the required "code" parameter.

My current code looks like:

```
firehose_trans_lambda = _lambda.CfnFunction(self, "FirehoseTransformLambda",
        description="foo", 
        code=, 
        handler="lambda_function.handler", 
        role="LambdaTransformRole.Arn",
        runtime="python3.8",
    )
```

According to the [CDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/CfnFunction.html), the "code" field should be of type (Union[Forwardref, IResolvable]).  I have no idea what this means, and the documentation isn't very helpful.  Does anybody have any insight as to what I could put in there to satisfy the requirements?  I was thinking of trying either a reference to some lambda or a piece of inline code, but am not sure how to go about doing that (I have tried various things, but my Python skills aren't the strongest).

Answer (score 2):

The `code` paramter expects an instance of `CfnFunction.CodeProperty`.  Its `__init__` accepts the following parameters (all optional and of type `str`)

- `s3_bucket`
- `s3_key`
- `s3_object_version`
- `zip_file`

You can pass the same values to `CfnFunction.CodeProperty()` that you've used in your CloudFormation template.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html

Afaik `CfnFunction.CodeProperty` isn't mentioned in the [AWS CDK Python Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/).  The general CDK documentation [mentions it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.CfnFunction.CodeProperty.html), but only as an interface.

Comment: Thank you! this solve my problems for the moment...on to the next.